# Lawn mower dies when blades are engaged

Tags: lawn-mower

I have a 1993 model Craftsman (917.257560) mower. I was having problems with it last weekend when I was trying to get it out. Charged the battery, checked the carb and checked the starter. Everything looked fine. I bypassed the seat safety cause I thought that was the culprit. Put everything back together and it started and purred like a kitten. It was too late to start mowing so I put her up.

Yesterday I was going to mow so I started it up and went to engage the blades and it died. I think there is a safety switch of some sort at the end of the engage/disengage lever under the dash. That is a whole other problem cause I can't figure out how to take the dash off... please advise.

Comment: Cross posting to [other sites](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/28917/511) is not good form here. If you want your question moved to a different stack, please flag it for moderator attention, and they can migrate it.

Comment: Are the blades bound up? Are all the pulleys aligned and free of debris?  Does the belt have a clear path?

Comment: The blades are not bound. Pulleys are fine and belts are fine. I can move the blades by hand.

Comment: This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaN6F5FDoY0) might be helpful, as it shows you how to access the interlock switch. Though I would replace the switch, rather than bypassing it.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to bypass it. I just want tips right now on how to get to it, if that is what we think the problem is. My mower is definitely not that easy to access.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than bypassing the various safety systems, either replace it (23 years is not an unreasonable retirement age for a mower) or have it properly repaired (since your "repair" methods don't appear to be oriented that way, take it to somone who **is** oriented that way.) Rendering the safety systems inoperable is a good way to find out why they were installed in the first place. Perhaps you'll have a child mowing the lawn someday with your customized mower...

Comment: While I understand your concern, I'm not going to pour money into a 23 year old tractor. Which happens to be the reason I'm on the DIY forum...

Comment: Ecnerwal, there's nothing wrong with temporarily bypassing a safety interlock for diagnostic purposes.  Atticus, parts are readily available cheap on Amazon of all places.  If you're going to use it, maintain it.  23 years old says nothing about its remaining service life.